# .tmp processes on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux

We are seeing 4 processes named 
[some arbitrary number].tmp

in the top command

Each one is consuming 40% CPU on a 8 core machine.

Any idea what those are?.

Comment: Are you running any other oracle software ? what if you run 'ps ax --forest' ? which is the parent process for those processes ? what does /proc/<PID>/cmdline contains ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope - not without some more information.

For starters, list the full command that's attached to the process in `top` with the 'c' hotkey; that should provide some insight into what's running.

If that's not illuminating, consider which user is running the processes, and what their parent processes are.

Finally, have a look at `lsof` (run as root or some processes will not be visible) to see what files and sockets the processes are using - that can help track down what they might be up to.

Hope that helps!